# What to do after a handler fails?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, handler, boost-asio

When a read operation handler returns an error, means that the connection is broken/failed/down? **Does it make any sense to start another asyncronous operation?**

I mean, the casuistry could be very complex depending on the different possible errors.

```
void ReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
   if(!error)
   {
      // OK
   }
   else
   {
      // does it make any sense to continue and start another async operation ?
      // or I have to check the error with error.value() and possibly close
      // the session or stop reading...etc ?
   }
```

How do I know if the connection still being usable? When a read error occurs with TCP layer below is because something went really wrong in the connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some value in understanding what the error itself is. But on the other hand, unless you have a comprehensive list of "which errors are OK to continue from, and which aren't OK", you pretty much end up with a "best guess" approach anyway.

Almost certainly some errors will be recoverable - temporarily not having enough buffer space to receive the packet, or some such. Other errors are permanent (someone unplugged the power to the network switch...).

One way to solve the problem is to have a counter of how many errors in a row you get - if you continue and don't get another error, then fine... If you get three (or five or ten or 100) errors in a row, you exit, as things are probably not getting any better

Another approach is to allow so many errors per a given time (e.g. more than 5 errors in 10 seconds, or more than 50 errors in a minute, or whatever makes some sense to your application).

The third approach is to ask the user - it really depends on the level of the user, what he/she will do given a message like "Got error X, do you want to continue? (Yes)|(No)" type question.

A large part of the question is of course "what is your application doing, and what is the consequence of 'getting it wrong' with regards to error handling?" - we can't really answer that without understanding more of your project - and really, that is probably a little beyond this websites guidelines to solve.

Comment: To be honest, I did not think on counting errors. It seems to be a good idea (not sure of how to close the socket if the first error is "mortal" because it is supposed that the handler will not be called again)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application, and even the async operation, what you do when a handler is invoked with a non-zero error. In most applications I typically handle [`boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html) differently than other errors because it means the program is shutting down. Depending on the protocol, you may wish to interpret [`boost::asio::error::eof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__misc_errors.html) differently as well. It may be entirely appropriate for the socket to be closed without notice.